# How did Soapy get to fly Hornets?

Tags: military, aviation-history, uk, fa-18

Allegedly, in early June 1983, while flying a [Sea Harrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_Sea_Harrier) during a NATO exercise off the coast of Portugal, Royal Navy's Sub-Lieutenant **Ian "Soapy" Watson** found himself in a rather unenviable predicament.  Allegedly, due to malfunctioning navigation systems, Soapy was unable to return to [HMS Illustrious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Illustrious_(R06)), the [Sea Harrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_Sea_Harrier) he was flying nearly ran out of fuel and, instead of ejecting into the Atlantic, Soapy decided to land on Spanish container ship [Alraigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alraigo_incident).

[image: Photo courtesy of JF Aleman-Canary Islands Spotting, according to https://www.forces.net/services/tri-service/day-royal-navy-pilot-landed-spanish-container-ship]

From the last paragraph of an [article](https://www.airspacemag.com/military-aviation/oldies-amp-oddities-the-alraigo-incident-10366728)$^\star$ on this famous incident:

> Watson eventually acquired 2,000 hours in Sea Harriers and another 900 in F/A-18s before resigning his commission in 1996.

To the best of my knowledge, neither the Royal Air Force (RAF) nor the Royal Navy ever acquired [F/A-18 Hornets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet). Thus, how did Soapy get to fly Hornets? Was he in some sort of exchange program between the Royal Navy and the [Royal Canadian Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_CF-18_Hornet) or the [Royal Australian Air Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_F/A-18_Hornet_in_Australian_service)? Or, perhaps, with the US Navy?$^\dagger$

---

<sub>$\star$ Tim Wright, [Oldies and oddities: the Alraigo Incident](https://www.airspacemag.com/military-aviation/oldies-amp-oddities-the-alraigo-incident-10366728), Air & Space Magazine, November 2008.</sub>

<sub>$\dagger$ Caroline Wyatt, [Royal Navy 'Top Gun' pilots train to fly US fighters](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-18041297), BBC News, 12 May 2012.</sub>